# How can I call a web api controller through window service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a local db that is access by a window application. I want this to put the data of this local db in my web server db. For this i have made a window application that will send the data of local db to my web api controller.
I don't know how to access  web api controller through window service...

Comment: i don;t want to use WCF instead of that i am using mvc-web api..

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: How can i use WCF to do so???

Comment: The underlying provider failed on Open.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "EduFameProjectDB18" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

I am trying to connect my window service to my local db. In my OnStart() method inside Service.cs class , i am gettging this error..

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is built for that.

See [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: Is it possible to send the data of local database  from window service to web api controller which in turn update it on the web db..

Comment: Yes, sure enough. The ApiController should expose a Post action, with data in parameter. With HttpClient, you can use the method HttpClient.PostAsync<ParameterType>(url, data, mediaTypeFormatter).

Comment: Can i add or update data to my web DB through The ApiController ??

Comment: What do you mean by "web db" ? If your ApiController has access to your db, then I do not see any issue. In your initial post, I understand that you have an ApiController which can read/update a db, and you have a Windows Service which cannot access to that db. So you Windows Service can send data to the ApiController. Your ApiController is then a bridge between the db and your Windows Service.

Comment: Now by using HttpClient I can access my apicontroller through window service..Thanks a lot..

Comment: The underlying provider failed on Open.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "EduFameProjectDB18" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

I am trying to connect my window service to my local db. In my OnStart() method inside Service.cs class , i am gettging this error..

Comment: You should create a dedicated question for this new problem. It seems the local system account does not have login access to your db. You can configure your db to allow it or change the service account (command "services.msc") to use an account allowed to access your db.